# Help with vacuous continuous function (please)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

i have a question that's been bugging me for the past two days. The definition of a function that is continuous at some point $a$ of it's domain, states: $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$$

That leaves me with two questions:

1) is $f$ vacuously continuous at $a$ if $f$ isn't defined at $x=a$ ?

2) If $\not\exists \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, is $f$ also vacuously continuous at $a$?

What i mean with "vacuously", is that the statement "$f$ is continuous at $a$" is vacuously true. For example, the stament "all the cellphones in the room are ringing" is vacuously true if there are no cellphones in the room to begin with. For that, i say that a function is continuous at $a$ if it isn't defined at that point in the first place, or if the limit doesn't exist. If either of those two happen, something that exists cannot be compared to something that doesn't exist.

Please end my misery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a function cannot be continuous at a point where it does not have a defined value.

If the function has a value at some point, but doesn't have a limit, then it is not continuous either.

The definition of continuity at a point should be something like (or equivalent to):

> A function is said to be **continuous** at a point $a$ in its domain if its limit for $x\to a$ *exists and equals the function value* at $a$.

It is common to abbreviate "exists and equals" to just "equals", but that doesn't change the meaning. Something that doesn't exist cannot equal anything, not even "vacuously".

In particular, the requirement is not that "*every* limit equals $f(a)$" (in which case it would indeed be relevant to speak about vacuous truth), but "*the* limit equals $f(a)$", which, as the words are commonly use, implies a claim that the limit is there so it can equal something.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i really apporeciate the help. I've also read that if $f$ is not defined at $a$, you can't really tell if it is or is not continuous at that point. For example, it is devoid of meaning to say whether $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous or not at $x=0$, since it isn't defined at that point.

Comment: @DavidAlexanderHulett: Yes, that's certainly a valid way of thinking, namely that "continuous" is only a meaningful property for points in the domain. That's the one I'm using in my wording of the definition above, and the one that seems to be most useful. For example, if we want to ask "at which points is the function _not_ continuous?" we typically wouldn't accept "green cheese" as an answer even though $f(\text{green cheese})$ is not defined. On the other hand sometimes people do say things like "$1/x$ is not continuous at $x=0$", and it rarely causes misunderstandings _in practice_.

Comment: I get your point. I just like to be really formal, and to accurately tell when an object is affected by a definition, in this case, to tell if a function can or can't be continuous at $a$ if it isn't defined at $a$. One would think the $\textit{domain}$ (if that's the word) of the definition comprises the set of functions that are well defined at the point $a$.

Comment: @DavidAlexanderHulett: Yes, that is a good way to express it.